# Arrays Group Counter

Tags: java, arrays, counter

Given a provided array, determine how many groups of a specified size exist.

For the array

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7]
```

there are 7 groups with at least one, 3 groups with at least 2, and 3 groups with at least 3.  A group is a series of same values. `1 1 1`  is a group of 3, but it also is a group of 1 and 2.  To count as a group, all values must be the same. `1 1 1` is a group of 3 because there are 3 1s in a row.

I'm just curious, how would this be done?

Comment: I think the first step is to disguise your homework better.

Comment: Iterate over the array, remember what the previous value was, detect changes that way, count the length of the current "run", accumulate in an array indexed by run length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used a set array where i looked at all the groups and did a loop to see each new number and if it was the same as the previous number. Which i have a group counter that is passed into a new array. Then the results are printed out.

public class Homework {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array_list = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
    int[] found_groups = new int[7];
    int group_size = 1; 
    int num_changed = 0; 
    for (int i = 1; i < array_list.length; i++) {

        if (array_list[i] == array_list[i-1]) {
            group_size++;

            if (group_size == 5) {
                found_groups[0] = group_size;
            }
            if (group_size == 3) {
                found_groups[2] = group_size; 
                found_groups[5] = group_size; 
            }
            if (group_size == 4) {
                found_groups[3] = group_size; 
            }
            if (group_size == 2) {
                found_groups[4] = group_size; 
            }
            if (group_size ==8) {
                found_groups[6] = group_size; 
            }
        }

        else if (array_list[i] != array_list[i-1]) {
            num_changed++;
            group_size = 1;
            if (group_size == 1) {
                found_groups[1] = group_size;
            }  
        }

    }

    int group_one = 0; 
    int group_two = 0; 
    int group_three = 0; 
    int group_four = 0; 
    int group_five = 0; 
    int group_six = 0; 
    int group_one_final = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < found_groups.length; i++) {
        if (found_groups[i] == 5) {
            group_five++; 
            group_two++;
            group_three++;
            group_four++;

        }
        if (found_groups[i] == 1) {
            group_one++; 
            group_one_final = group_one + num_changed; 
        }
        if (found_groups[i] == 3) {
            group_three++; 
            group_two++;
        }
        if (found_groups[i] == 4) {
            group_four++;
            group_two++;
            group_three++;

        }
        if (found_groups[i] == 8) {
            group_six++; 
            group_two++; 
            group_three++;
            group_four++;
            group_five++;
        }
        if (found_groups[i] == 2) {
            group_two++; 

        }
    }

    System.out.println("number of ones groups: " + group_one_final);
    System.out.println("number of two groups: " + group_two);
    System.out.println("number of three groups: " + group_three );
    System.out.println("number of fours groups: " + group_four);
    System.out.println("number of fives groups: " + group_five);
    System.out.println("number of sixes groups: " + group_six);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8

```
long result = Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() >= 1) // specify the size
        .count();
System.out.println(result);
```